# iOS Voiceover status

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am trying to add accessibility features to an iOS app that has already been developed.

There are a couple of UI features (e.g. buttons) that I like them to show up if the VoiceOver option in the accessibility menu of the iPhone settings is on and do not show up if the voiceover is off.

Is there a way to check whether the voiceover option is on or not?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
BOOL UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning();
```

Comment: Is similar feature available for Mac?

Comment: My Cocoa is too rusty to answer, but it looks like no. Maybe ask on the Apple developer forum.

Comment: In Swift: `UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning`

Answer (score 36):

In ViewDIdLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(voiceOverStatusChanged)
                                             name:UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged
                                           object:nil];


- (void)voiceOverStatusChanged
{
    if(!UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning())
    {
        //do your changes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

For Swift 4.2 and newer versions, you can check the following boolean provided by UIKit:

`UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning`

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to all the previous correct answers, since iOS11 and according to this [Accessibility options recap](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#accessibility-options), the new notification name to be used is :

- `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChange` (SWIFT < 4.2).
- `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification` (ObjC).

... while `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged` is deprecated.

**EDIT** for **SWIFT 4.2** ==> `UIAccessibility.voiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification`